# check if folder does not exist in tcsh

Tags: scripts, tcsh

When using the tcsh shell, how do I check if a folder does NOT exist?

I can check if it exists by

```
if ( -d /folder ) then
```

but I want the if statement to work for folders that don't exist.

Comment: What should happen if `/folder` is present, but a file? Or a link? Or some other type?

Answer (score 4):

Just use

```
if (! -d /folder ) then
    #run some code here, if the folder does not exist
```

Answer (score 2):

One thing you could do is use an `else`:

```
#!/usr/bin/tcsh

if ( -d folder) then 

else
        echo no
endif
```

Alternatively, you can do a negative check:

```
#!/usr/bin/tcsh

if (! -d folder) then 
   echo "No such folder"
```

Answer (score 0):

The following script will check for the existence of the directory. If the directory does not exist, it is going to be created

```
#!/usr/bin/tcsh
if ( -e directory_name ) then
   echo 'Directory "directory_name" exists'
else
   mkdir directory_name
   echo 'Directory "directory_name" created'
endif
```